# How to put an image inside a function definition?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button

I want to put an image inside my dice function I would really appreciate if someone can tell me what I need to add so I can have the image as the background of the page

```
def dice():
    tk = Tk()
    tk.geometry('300x300')
    img = PhotoImage(file='dicee.gif')
    lb5 = Label(tk,image=img)
    lb5.pack()

btn4=Button(tk,text="Roll The Dice",command=dice)
btn4.place(x=110,y=130)
tk.mainloop()
```

The error it shows me is:

```
 self.tk.call(
   _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Comment: The root of the problem is that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`. For a second window you need to use `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are *two* separate problems with your code. One is that you're creating multiple instances of `Tk()` which is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) as @Bryan Oakley mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103175/how-to-put-an-image-inside-a-function-definition/70104295#comment123924255_70103175) — create a [`Toplevel`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html) window widget instead.

The other issue is that you're creating the `PhotoImage` in a function, and since it's a local variable it will be garbage collected when the function returns (see [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function))

Here's code showing how to fix both issues:

```
from tkinter import *

def dice():
    tk = Toplevel()  # Create new window.
    tk.geometry('300x300')
    img = PhotoImage(file='dicee.gif')
    lb5 = Label(tk, image=img)
    lb5.img = img  # Save reference to image.
    lb5.pack()

tk = Tk()
btn4 = Button(tk, text="Roll The Dice", command=dice)
btn4.place(x=110, y=130)
tk.mainloop()
```